# How to account for an argument to my method being `null` instead of an `int`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullable

I need to know how to account for an argument to my method being `null` instead of an `int` .

I have this method which is supposed to receive an int

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateUser(int userId){ }
```

However when ever the session times out and I log back in while in the middle of calling this method it receives a `null` instead of an `int`.

This causes this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'userId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UpdateUser(Int32)' in
>   'Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I need a way to account for receiving a `null` argument.

So far I have tried overloading the method with a nullable int type like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateUser(int? userId){ }
```

but this just ends up receiving every UpdateUser() call and converting the value to `null`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need the first method. The second method will handle both situations...a null or an int. If its a null...redirect to... what...a login screen?

Comment: When I have the second method implemented it seems to override the first method on every call. Its purpose is to catch events where the int value is lost due to a session timeout, however when implemented it overrides the UpdateUser(int userId) method and the value is always converted to a null. The purpose is to catch the uncommon event that would error out and yes, redirect to a new page.

Comment: After re-reading your comment I see you said I don't need the first method, however the problem is that the second method seems to be converting the value to null where the first method does not.

Comment: The parameter your passing needs to be int? also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for the overload, which won't be supplied the `userId` is probably:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateUser(){ }
```

i.e. no userId was supplied, rather than it being supplied with a `null` value.

I say "probably" as it is possible that your request does in fact have the parameter/argument specified with no value.

If this is the case, you should probably use just the one signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int? userId){ }
```

With a check...

```
if (userId.HasValue)
{
    // ok... you can use userId.Value
}
else
{
    // not ok...
}
```

Comment: I tired both of these methods here and it appears when I use your first solution I get this error "The current request for action 'UpdateUser' on controller type 'UserController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UpdateUser() on type Controllers.UserController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UpdateUser(Int32) on type Controllers.UserController"

Comment: When I use your second solution I get a null value sent to userId no matter what. It doesn't error out, but it gets a null value when it should be getting an int value.

Comment: This ended up being the solution. Your second solution worked for me after some time working with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply use the signature

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int? userId = 0){ }
```

This should check to see if it is null and if it is, set it to 0.